# Слово "флудить"

Tags: лексика

Что означает слово "флудить"?

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю. Флудить - заниматься флудом. 
Флуд - от английского flood - наводнение (в одном из значений). Поток пустых, ничего не значащих сообщений, посылаемых отдельными пользователлями от нечего делать или злонамерено, связывали именно с этим стихийным бедствием. Потом значение несколько изменилось, флудом стали считать любое сообщение не по теме дискуссии.

Надо сказать, что в плане квалификации деяния единого подхода к тому, что считать флудом, нет. На разных ресурсах - разные представления.

Comment: Меня больше интересует другое. Слово [flood][1] произносится скорее как "флад", чем "флуд" (как и слово blood - никому не придет в голову его переводить как "блуд"). Так почему же в русском устаканился неправильный вариант произношения?

[1]:http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/flood

Comment: Может, просто потому, что в blood возникает посторонний смысл? Для не очень знающего English человека -oo- воспринимается как -у-.

Answer (score 2):

Флуд — это разговор не по теме интернет-сообщества, форума, чата или другого тематического ресурса.